# Vitamio Error In Android - Native libs libffmpeg.so not exists

Tags: android, video, rtmp, vitamio

I've been trying to play streaming videos with Vitamio 4.2.2 but it has not worked for me. I can't play rtmp videos with vitamio because it generates this error in the logcat : E/Vitamio[Player]: Native libs libffmpeg.so not exists!. however i can play others video formats such as : rtsp , http. but not rtmp. I've searching a lot about this error, but i can find a solution.

I am very grateful if someone can assist me a little about what's going on that error.

Answer (score 7):

Use a Physical Android device to test. Emulators not support to Vitamio.

Comment: You can use VLC open source player as replacement to Vitamio. VLC has many advance features.